# Comparing Text in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, sql-like

I have one table with text column and another table with keywords column. Now i want to get all the text containing the keywords in another table. I tried using LIKE operator but it is not working. My query looks like this

```
select screen_name from t_tweets_geo where text like '% select keywords from h_trends %';
```

But this query is not returning anything. Kindly Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select is inside a string literal in your command . Hence it is not executed ..

you can use this instead

```
select screen_name from t_tweets_geo,h_trends where text LIKE concat('%',keywords,'%')
```

note that this doesn't remove duplicates ..

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not work, because it is unlikely that any of the keywords columns contain the string `' select keywords from h_trends '.

One approach is to use `join`:

```
select g.screen_name
from t_tweets_geo g join
     h_trends h
     on concat(' ', text, ' ') like concat(' ', h.keywords, ' %') ;
```

However, the better way to store keywords for an entity is to use a separate table, with one row per `screen_name` and `keyword`.  Storing lists of values in a single string is fraught with danger.

Comment: Actually i have twitter data and all i want is to find the screen name of the persons who is using those keywords in their text. Your query is returning this error : FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:8 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '' %''